# How to create WPF responsive menu bar (full-width)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application which has a Full screen with `WindowState="Maximized"` enabled but I can not doc the `Menu` to display full screen. I removed the `width` property from the window but still displaying the menu in small part of the screen.

How can I make the Menu to behave responsive?

```
<Window x:Class="UMAp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UBrochure"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid Background="Gray" >
        <Menu x:Name="menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <Button Content="Edit" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FFF0F0F0"/>
            <Button BorderThickness="0" Content="  Templates" Background="#FFF0F0F0"/>
        </Menu>
        <Grid Background="#FF51514B" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="291" Margin="0,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What I did to get this working:**

1. Set the with and height of the menu to Auto
2. Set the alignments to Stretch on all alignments.
3. Also I'd divided the grid in two columns header and body and set the first column height to a maximum height so it doesn't become to large when the program is full screen.

```html
<Grid Background="Gray" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="15" Height="10*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu x:Name="menu" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <Button Content="Edit" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FFF0F0F0"/>
        <Button BorderThickness="0" Content="  Templates" Background="#FFF0F0F0"/>
    </Menu>
    <Grid Background="#FF51514B" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="291" Margin="0,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Timon but why do we have to change the height of menu? How can I keep it at previous height?

Comment: You need that for defining the size of the grid row what you have is a grid but that grid has only one row and column, by doing this I specify that the menu is a certain height and the second column has the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use `DockPanel` instead of a `Grid` as your outer container.  Set the menu's `DockPanel.Dock="Top"` and it will automatically adjust its size without you having to hard-code anything.  Any child of the `DockPanel` will dock against the specified side of the window, in the order they appear in XAML.  If `LastChildFill` is `true` (it is by default), the last child will automatically fill up any remaining space.  You can create some fairly complex layout using this method.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="FilterWithBindableCount.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button Content="Edit" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FFF0F0F0"/>
            <Button BorderThickness="0" Content="Templates" Background="#FFF0F0F0"/>
        </Menu>
        <Grid>
            <!--Grid content here-->
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

One of the key to successfully using WPF is know what all the different [layout containers](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/) are, and when to use them.